# Some users cannot login to my google app

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, google-signin

I have developed a node.js application which has a google login. I developed the google login using.

```
"passport": "^0.3.2"
"passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0"
```

My concern is, except few users all the others can access this.

Here is the implementation

```
[..]

module.exports = function (passport, config) {

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        console.log(user.id);
        done(null, user);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
        console.log("before derializing");
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.use(
        new GoogleStrategy(
            {
                clientID: config.googleAuth.clientID,
                clientSecret: config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
                callbackURL: config.googleAuth.callbackURL
            },
            function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
                process.nextTick(function () {
                    console.log("user is authenticated" + profile.displayName);
                    //TODO sign up
                    done(null, profile);
                });
            }
        )
    );
};
```

Appreciate you assistance

Comment: Do you have any exception, or some other additional information?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.....

In this I had maintained the profile (the profile object comes from google) as the session object. And some profile objects contains special characters that causes errors when setting up the session in passport.

So, maintaining a separate object for the session solved this issues as shown below.

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: config.googleAuth.clientID,
            clientSecret: config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: config.googleAuth.callbackURL
        },
        function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function () {
                console.log("user is authenticated" + profile.displayName);
                //TODO sign up
                done(null, {
                   displayName: profile.displayName
                });
            });
        }
    )
);
```